# DataBases requests

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a beginner in the field of developing and I have a database that contains 3 tables which are citizen, city, country:

citizen: with 2 fields Id and Id_City

city: with 2 fields Id and Id_Country

country: with one field Id

My issue is to get what country a citizen X belongs to.
My approach is more like 2 requests:

1st. `select Id_Country from citizen where Id=X`

2nd. using the result from the first request
`select from city Id_Country where Id ="the id_city i got in the result of the first request"`

and after that using an other request to get more infos of the country if needed

So i wonder if i could do all of that in one request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join:

```
SELECT country.Country_Name
  FROM citizen
  JOIN city ON citizen.Id_City = city.Id
  JOIN country ON city.Id_Country = country.Id
 WHERE citizen.Id = [x];
```